# Securing Jenkins login

Tags: ssl, jenkins

I've installed Jenkins through its [official Docker image](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/official-jenkins-lts-docker-image), got a non-SSL-enabled Jenkins instance, enabled user logins through Jenkins' own user database, but it seems passwords are sent unencrypted, unhashed, in plain-text inside JSON (at least, I could see the password through Chrome's Network tab of the Developer Console). If that's indeed happening, it seems evil, so either I screwed up, or Jenkins isn't suitable for production use. Especially, this does not seem to be documented — I only found [this post](https://toolkit.cit-ec.uni-bielefeld.de/blog/new-jenkins-including-ssl-encryption-and-mandatory-login-deployed), by googling (for instance) `jenkins authentication password encryption`.

What is the underlying problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: why non-ssl? You can always see a password as it gets sent to and from the server if you aren't using ssl. there's no client-side encryption going on. Go login to your bank with fiddler enabled and you'll see the same thing.

Comment: You might take my question as "why did the provider of the Docker image not provide SSL?", except that I don't know whether that's what he intended users to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are not using SSL. There is nothing special about a password field in HTML other than that browsers don't display their contents. If you are doing any sort of web sniffing you will be able to see all communication between the browser and the server, including passwords, unless the site is using SSL.

I recommend using a self signed certificate and get SSL going on your server.

As I said in my comment - go download [fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and set it up to [allow https decryption](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp). Then go login to your bank. You'll see your password clear as day in the traffic - because it's no longer encrypted by SSL.